# Create Outlet and Action without Storyboard for UISlider in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uislider

I have an UISlider created in my main file as a property, and I would like to perform some actions when his valueDidChange.

My UISlider isn't in the Xib File, how can I create the valueDidChange action without CTRL + Drag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to add below line of code in your view controller.

```
[yourslidername addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChangedMethodcall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)sliderValueChangedMethodcall:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSLog(@"slider value change= %f", sender.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents` and specify `UIControlEventValueChanged` as the control event.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the slider:

```
-(IBAction)mySlider
{ 
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 25.0;
    [self.view addSubview:slider];
}
```

And to give your slider an action:

```
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
    float value = slider.value;
    //-- Do further actions
}
```